# Count Unique Values with Filter Support

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns that represent Cities and Countries respectively that I would like to count the unique entries.  Example data here:

```
C1:C5           D1:D5
Managua         Nicaragua
Providenciales  Turks and Caicos
Mont Tremblant  Canada
Whistler        Canada
San Salvador    El Salvador
```

So far I have a formula with a mix of SUM, MATCH and FREQUENCY functions that correctly displays the unique count as 5 and 4 respectively.

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH($C$1:C5,$C$1:C5,0),MATCH($C$1:C5,$C$1:C5,0))>0,1))
```

The problem is when I filter the columns the formula still shows the totals for the sheet not the filter filtered totals.  For example, if I filtered column D to remove Canada, the formula should return 3 and 3.

Is this possible?  I tried SUBTOTAL but couldn't get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this puppy a try:

```
=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(C1,ROW(C1:C5)-ROW(C1),0,1)),MATCH(C1:C5,C1:C5,0)),ROW(C1:C5)-ROW(C1)+1)>0,1))
```

Comment: Hmm, it's working for me.  When you enter the formula, use ctrl+shift+enter to make it act as an array formula and see if that works for you.

Comment: That did it!  that key combination is new to me - thanks